# Extract a namespace and it's URI from the outermost element

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, extract, text-extraction

I am trying to extract the value of two attributes in the outermost element of an XML instance. The attributes are:

```
xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance"
xmlns:us-gaap="http://xbrl.us/us-gaap/2009-01-31"
```

So far using XQuery hasn't paid off because:

1. You have to declare the namespaces before you write down a query to do the job and the URI's are not always the same
2. Commands such as this one:

   ```
   declare namespace xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance";
   doc("oba.xml")/xbrli:xbrl/string(@us-gaap)
   ```

   ...still give no results.

I am open to any methodology that is as rigid as it can possibly be and may reliably extract a namespace of choice from the outermost element of any instance document.

The outermost element is:

```
<xbrli:xbrl xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" xmlns:aem="http://www.agnico-eagle.com/20091231" xmlns:dei="http://xbrl.us/dei/2009-01-31" xmlns:dei-std="http://xbrl.us/dei-std/2009-01-31" xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217" xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase" xmlns:ref="http://www.xbrl.org/2006/ref" xmlns:us-gaap="http://xbrl.us/us-gaap/2009-01-31" xmlns:us-gaap-all="http://xbrl.us/us-gaap-all/2009-01-31" xmlns:us-gaap-std="http://xbrl.us/us-gaap-std/2009-01-31" xmlns:us-roles="http://xbrl.us/us-roles/2009-01-31" xmlns:us-types="http://xbrl.us/us-types/2009-01-31" xmlns:xbrldi="http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi" xmlns:xbrldt="http://xbrl.org/2005/xbrldt" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are namespace declarations and not attributes!

Perhaps something like the following in XQuery 1.0:

```
declare namespace xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance";

let $xbrl := fn:doc("oba.xml")/xbrli:xbrl
let $prefixes := fn:in-scope-prefixes($xbrl)
return
    for $prefix in $prefixes
    return
        fn:namespace-uri-for-prefix($prefix, $xbrl)
```

A further follow-up below based on the comments "I am need of something that will literally take only the outermost element and search it step by step and and give a URI per prefix. Thank you for your great help." and " I need something to be very rigid so i cant declare namespace xbrli up there. As far as i am concerned XBRL isn' t stable anywhere so taking a URI that may change on another instance may create quite a problem":

```
let $outer-most := fn:doc("oba.xml")/element()
let $prefixes := fn:in-scope-prefixes($outer-most)
return
    for $prefix in $prefixes
    return
        fn:namespace-uri-for-prefix($prefix, $outer-most)
```

Comment: Dear @adamretter i have tested your solution. I didn't have time so sorry for my late response. I need something to be very rigid so i cant `declare namespace xbrli` up there. As far as i am concerned XBRL isn' t stable anywhere so taking a `URI` that may change on another instance may create quite a problem.

Comment: I am need of something that will literally take only the `outermost element` and search it step by step and and give a URI per prefix. Thank you for your great help.